# How to get name from a value in an R vector with names

Tags: r

I know that with a vector such as

```
v <- c("MA", "NY", "PA")
names(v) <- c("Massachusetts", "New York", "Pennsylvania")
```

It is possible to get a value from a name using syntax such as

```
v["New York"]
```

But is it possible to get a name from a value (like the PHP key() function)? Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this.

```
names(v)[v == "NY"] # extract the names, subset by equality to NY
# or
names(which(v == "NY")) # extract entries that == NY and get names
```

to name a few.

Comment: names(v)[v == "NY"] looks like the easiest syntax, thank you. Still wish there were a basic function like key() though. Will have to write my own to use in my own code.

Comment: Just be careful about NAs when using this syntax:
v <- c("MA", "NY", "PA",NA);
names(v) <- c("Massachusetts", "New York", "Pennsylvania","Guam");
names(v)[v=="NY"];
#[1] "New York" NA

Answer (score 8):

Use match

```
names(v)[match("NY",v)]
```

or use which

```
names(v)[which(v=="NY")]
```

Comment: I prefer the ``match()`` approach - it's cleaner. My vote goes here. ``thumbs-up to you man !!!``